# HTML/CSS question: Part of div being floated to next line, I want it on the same line

Tags: php, mysql, html, css, database

I am loading names/grades from a database which happens perfectly... however, the grade assosciated with the person is for some reason getting floated down to the next line and I can't figure out why, as you can see in this picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqhjp.png

I want that number grade to be on the same line, aligned on the right, but I cant figure out why it's getting pushed down to the next line. Here is my php:

```
echo '<div class = "name">' . $firstname . " "  . $lastname . "<strong>" . '<p align="right">' . $avg . '</p></strong></div>';
```

And the CSS it refers to:

}

```
#content .name{
    background: #FFF;
    float:left; 
    width: 220px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    border: 2px solid #CCC;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Instead of the PHP echo, just include one of the lines of HTML it creates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `p` and `align`, put the grade in a `span` and `float` it to the right. You can see it working in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/UK6BN/).

Comment: Cool! I haven't used spans much yet, I'm just getting into this... thank you very much. I'll accept this answer soon as it allows me.

Comment: No problem. The issue with the `p` tag, as mentioned by @Dickie in his answer, was that as a block element it takes 100% of the width of its container. It also adds space above and below it, which caused it to be pushed further down. Also note that you should really be using CSS (as I do with the `float:right` in my example) rather than attributes like `align`.

Answer (score 1):

'p' is a block element and takes, by default, 100% width.
You can either set a width on the p tag or float right.

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you want to display every person you should use table instead of divs